# Получение value для iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, img

Есть у меня код, который получает `value` выпадающего списка и выводит картинку, путь которой указан в `value` каждого элемента списка. Теперь же стала необходимость выводить другой html документ, а заменить `<img>` на `<iframe>` так просто не получилось. Форумчане, помогите пожалуйста. В JS слаб пока что.
Вот код который использую для вывода картинки

```html
<img id="img" src="value" align="middle" />
  <script>
    var select = document.getElementById('categories'),
      img = document.getElementById('img');
    select.addEventListener('change', changeImg.bind(this),false)
    function changeImg(elem) {
      img.src = elem.target.value
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Поменял `img` на `iframe`, проблем не возникло, в чем проблема?

Comment: Приведу код в ответе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут все просто:

```html
<select id="categories">
 <option>Выберите из списка</option>
 <option value="http://site.com/">site.com</option>
 <option value="http://site.com/">site.com</option>
</select>

<iframe id="iframe" src="value" align="middle"></iframe>
  <script>
    var select = document.getElementById('categories'),
      iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
     select.addEventListener('change', changeImg.bind(this),false)
    function changeImg(elem) {
      iframe.src = elem.target.value
    }
 </script>
```

Главное чтобы в заголовках сайта, который будет отображаться в `iframe` не было `X-Frame-Options: DENY`

Comment: Спасибо, оказалось все просто) Изначально не додумался, видимо усталость берет свое

Comment: Надо отдыхать, конечно)